# SQL Server 2008 date exclusion

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figure out a way to perform a query which will obtain all data greater than six months old, without any data that is newer. I will see if I can appropriately summarize:

```
select u.USER_FirstName, u.USER_LastName, 
    u.USER_LastSession, c.Login_Name

FROM USER u
   JOIN Customer c
      ON u.USER_Customer_Identity=c.Customer_Identity

Where u.USER_LastSession < getdate()-180

Order by USER_LastSession
```

This is what I've found on SO so far, but the issue lies in that the USER.USER_LastSession records values for each log in (so some Customer.Login_Name values are unnecessary to return). I *only* want the ones which are greater than six months, with no result returned if they are *also* recorded at time less than six months. Example data:

USER_LastSession          Login_Name

2012-08-29 21:33:30.000   TEST/TEST

2012-12-25 13:12:23.346   EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE

2013-10-30 17:13:45.000   TEST/TEST

I would not want to return TEST/TEST, since there is data in the past six months. I would, however, like to return EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE, since it only has data that is older than six months. I imagine there is probably something that I have overlooked - please forgive me if there is already an answer up for this (I was only able to find a "get older than six months" reply). Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
FROM User u
JOIN Customer c ON u.USER_Customer_Identity=c.Customer_Identity
WHERE u.USER_Customer_Identity NOT IN
    (SELECT USER_Customer_Identity
     FROM User
     WHERE USER_LastSession >= getdate() - 180)
ORDER BY USER_LastSession
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
    select Login_Name, max(USER_LastSession) LastSession
    FROM USER u
    JOIN Customer c
        ON u.USER_Customer_Identity = c.Customer_Identity
    group by Login_Name
)

select *
from cte
where LastSession < getdate()-180
```

Comment: This is poor design however... user table should only have the user information once. And this sort of session login information should be housed elsewhere... perhaps a log table.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. =) I'm trying to get around it - I think this did the trick. Thanks very much for your response!